# How to resolve Error Starting Kernel in JupyterLab

Tags: python, installation, jupyter-lab

I know there are a lot of similar questions, that have already been solved out there, but the solutions are a bit too complex for me.

Long story short, I am not good at installing things and getting them up and running at all. Took me months to work out how to install JupyterLab.

But I finally did it! and I even set up a piece of Batch code to launch it in my current directory.

```
C:\anaconda3\python.exe C:\anaconda3\cwp.py C:\anaconda3\ C:\anaconda3\python.exe C:\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-lab-script.py "%CD%"
```

However, now I am getting this error
[Error Starting Kernal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZ5wL.png)

Is there a simple way to address this issue? Do I just need to move my kernel script to the right folder? Add something to redirect the batch file to find the kernel?

Answer (score 0):

Run this command to fix the error

```
python -m ipykernel install --user
```

Comment: Actually, I ended up uninstalling all of my Python and Anaconda stuff because I couldn't import any of the packages and thought it might be due to there being multiply python programs on my computer.
Then I re-installed just Anaconda and now this command no longer works...